# Ejabberd muc room history getting erased when server restarts

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, multiuserchat, strophe.js

I am subscribing to a muc room and I am getting the messages when a user messages to muc room, everything upto here is fine, but when server restarts room history is getting erased, therefore I am unable to get any previous messages.

This is my mod_muc configuration in ejabberd.yml:

```
mod_mam:
 default: always
 db_type: sql
mod_muc:
access:
  - allow
access_admin:
  - allow: admin
access_create: muc_create
access_persistent: muc_create
default_room_options:
  mam: true
  persistent: true
```

Answer (score 0):

> when server restarts room history is getting erased

Right, because that recent history is not stored in any database, it is kept in temporary memory, like the list of current occupants. When the server stops, all that is forgotten.